# How does backslash work with grep in the bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I am trying to match this expression to test the backslash with grep:

> '\u\v'

When I wrote this regex:

> '\\u\\v'

the whole expression matched the regex, but when I wrote `\u` only expecting the regex to fail since there is no character `\u`,`\v`(there are `\t`,`\n`), It matched the **u** of the given string.

How is it that **`\u`** regex matches the u character?

Answer (score 3):

It helps to [read a description](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/regex.7.html) of the (regex) language you use.

We learn from it that, unlike in C string literals, `\n` means literal `n` and `\t` means literal `t`. Likewise, `\u` means literal `u`.

> An  atom is [.....],  a  '\'  followed  by  any other character(!)
>   (matching that character taken as an ordinary character, as if the 
>   '\' had  not  been  present(!)) [......]